# knowing whether bitlocker or bitlocker togo is used on a drive

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-7, bitlocker

I am trying to make out whether `bitlocker` or `bitlocker togo`(i.e. bitclocker on removable drive) is used to encrypt a drive. so basically its about knowing the `volumeType` as seen by `bitlocker`.
I tried using WMI class `Win32_EncryptableVolume` to get this information.
The interface has a property [volumetype](http://wutils.com/wmi/root/cimv2/security/microsoftvolumeencryption/win32_encryptablevolume/#volumetype_properties).
The way works fine in windows 10. In windows 7 the Win32_EncryptableVolume class is not having a property `volumeType`.

So is there a alternate way to know this ? i want to know whether bitlocker or bitlocker togo  is used that will be same as knowing if a volume is removable or fixed.
I have tried using manage-bde.exe but that also does not give information about this.

So is there a way we can get this information for windows 7 ?

One thing is that this information is not same as how windows sees the drive as since there is a difference in the way bitlocker treats a volume([ref](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/e8e78e90-e98e-492d-be0d-23a3bcf19c75/bitlocker-fixed-vs-removable-drives?forum=winserver8gen)). So i cannot use interfaces such as `wmic logicaldisk`.

Comment: So are you trying to check locally on a windows 7 machine, or are you checking the machine remotely?

Comment: @DrewLean It can be anycase. i have checked it in local as well as remote system. windows 7 is not having the property volumeType in Win32_EncryptableVolume class.